# unity3d - Instantiate and fire bullet relative to player rotation in 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, topdown

This is a top-down view but in 3D coordinates, I would like to instantiate and fire a bullet from the player's gun. This script is on a spawner object at the end of the barrel. Also tried putting the script on the player itself but also didn't work.

```
GameObject projectile =  Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
 projectile.GetComponent().AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
```

The problem is the bullets doesn't behave as intended, instead they don't appear relative to the player rotation they just go in a very different direction. Shouldn't "Transform.Forward" mean forward in the Z position regarding the object's transform ?

Comment: You might get better answers from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanck you, will try that.